# Using boost::interprocess offset_ptr

Tags: c++, boost

I need to store the structure for Quadtree in shared memory.

It is a class with 4 pointers for tree-node regions and vector of points:

```
class CSNode4
{
...
CSNode4* node0;
CSNode4* node1;
CSNode4* node2;
CSNode4* node3;
vector<vec2> pointArray;
};
```

I have tried with

```
class CSNode4
{
...
offset_ptr<CSNode4> node0;
offset_ptr<CSNode4> node1;
...
};
```

and using as:

```
typedef allocator<void,  managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> void_allocator;
const void_allocator alloc_void(segment.get_segment_manager());
CSNode4* rootNode = segment.construct<CSNode4> (_RootNode) (alloc_void);
rootNode->node0 = new CSNode4(alloc_void,...);
```

this works OK until I try to static_cast node0:

```
offset_ptr<CSNode4> N1 = static_cast<CSNode4*>(rootNode->node0);
```

I get:

error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from   'boost::interprocess::offset_ptr' to 'CSNode4 *'

(MSVC 2010, boost 1.42)

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the CSNode4 is equivalent to CNode4. Since node0 is a offset_ptr, of course you can't static_cast it to a pointer of CSNode4. You should use the copy constructor of offset_ptr directly:

```
boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<CSNode4> N1(rootNode->node0);
```

Comment: Thanks, 
but still not working, now I get:
Access violation reading location 0x0075...
I have also tried using get() member:
offset_ptr<CSNode4> node0_pt;
node0_pt = rootNode->node0;
(node0_pt.get())->
...Also not working...

Other:
 CNode4 instead of CSNode4 was syntax, changed that
, allocator is only used for vector member, should not influence this?